# How to include files in sub folder

Tags: php

I am having a folder structure like this.

```
[My root]
    [Admin]
      [includes]
         header.php
         footer.php
     index.php
    [assets]
    [classes]
    [db]
    [includes]
    [templates]
index.php
```

I want to include files like header and footer pages which are in the Admin includes folder into my index page which is in the admin folder.

I tried the following way,

```
include('../Admin/includes/header.php');
```

I am not able to include those files.

I would like to know how to include those files.

Comment: It should be like `include('includes/header.php');`

Comment: What exactly does not work with the given code?

Answer (score 0):

Change `include('../Admin/includes/header.php');` to `include('./Admin/includes/header.php');`

Comment: I changed what you said. but it throws an error like  Warning: include(./Admin/includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in

Comment: i would like to know what ls -R is. i don't  understand what you try to say.

Comment: Or you can `print_r(__DIR__) here`.

Answer (score 0):

`include('./Admin/includes/header.php');`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code.

- `include('Admin/includes/header.php');`

  **Or**
- `require_once('Admin/includes/header.php');`

Answer (score 0):

this way works to me,

```
$actual_link = (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] === 'on' ? "https" : "http") . "://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";

        include($actual_link . '/includes/header.php');
```